# Can javascript delete a cookie set by http header?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies

I try to delete cookie set by http header but doesn't work. What's the different between http-set cookie and javascript-set cookie ?

Comment: The answer is in here: [How to Delete Session Cookie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie). If a cookie is set with `HttpOnly`, you cannot access it from JS.

Comment: Are they HTTPOnly cookies? Can your JavaScript read them?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, javascript can delete a cookie set by HTTP headers unless it is specifically a [HTTPOnly](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly) cookie.

The cookie must also be from the same domain as the javascript.

See also http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
 and [Clearing all cookies with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179355/clearing-all-cookies-with-javascript#179514)