# How to delete cookie with HttpOnly using PHP or JS

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, cookie-httponly

I have a cookie with these parameters:

```
Name:   workgroup_session_id
Content:    ""
Domain: agrobman1.tsi.lan
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   No (HttpOnly)
Created:    Wednesday, November 4, 2015 at 9:31:58 AM
Expires:    When the browsing session ends
```

I have tried to delete the cookie using PHP using this code:

```
setcookie("workgroup_session_id", "\"\"", time() - 3600, "/", "agrobman1.tsi.lan", false, true);
```

But I am still unable to delete it. Does anyone know how to delete a cookie of this type using PHP or JS?

Answer (score 75):

You cannot delete an HttpOnly cookie on the client-side with javascript, as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie) points out. It has to be done on the server side with node.js.

Comment: Actually you can if you are using node.js on server side... :D

Comment: Ahahah, you mean that we can delete it with JS )))