# Angular 8 - Clear cookies using CookieService

Tags: angular, cookies, jsessionid

I'm trying to clear all the info my app is saving in the browser, whether it's in sessionStorage, localStorage or cookies.

I've added this small method to do so, and it get called in the `ngOnInit` of one of my components:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.clearAppData();
    }

    private clearAppData(): void {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        localStorage.clear();
        this.cookieService.deleteAll();
}
```

`sessionStorage` and `localStorage` seems to be cleared, yet I can see that the cookies are not.
I need to manually clear the cookies through the browser.

Moreover, sometimes I see that the cookie is saved under the root path, and sometimes I see it under the relative root path. I'm not sure what is the cause of this, and as sometimes it sends the wrong cookie, I would like to clear everything before getting a new one.

[image]

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Edit the question with CookieService

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same issue.
if your cookie is customized which means secure, Strict, Path then you need to clear with specifications.

`this._cookieService.delete("cookie name","/","domain name",true,"None");`

I am sure this should work for you.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, unfortunately I'm no longer developing with Angular, yet I'd give it a thumbs up as it seems to be the right way.

Answer (score 2):

In the development environment `localhost`; any client side app using  UI frameworks will need to tweak the server session cookie code as below.

Note: On your backend server you need to turn the cookie setting for `httpOnly` to `False` as below code

```
cookie: {
       secure: false, //set this to true in production over https
       httpOnly: false, //set this to false in development to test delete 
       ....
       ....
}
```

Later, in your Angular service code for logout method use as below:

```
logout(){

this.cookieService.delete('<your-cookie-name>', '/', 'localhost', false, 'Lax');

}
```

[See ngx-cookie-service documentation](https://github.com/stevermeister/ngx-cookie-service#delete-name-string-path-string-domain-string-secure-boolean-samesite-lax--none--strict--lax-void)

For individual delete:

```
delete( name: string, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict' = 'Lax'): void;
```

For Batch delete:

```
deleteAll( path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite: 'Lax' | 'None' | 'Strict' = 'Lax' ): void;
```

Important: On production both should be set as True | httpOnly & Secure | for a Cookie

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ngx-cookie-service?

Please check the execution order of your code and set the path to '/'

I've been fiddling around with it and it seems that setting a cookie with the same name will override the existing one. So you will not see your cookie being deleted if the order is incorrect.

I had no time to check the path-section you mentioned. I did not implement a router with paths to see if i could help you with that.

Setting a cookie with:
Service.setcookie('name', 'value', int, '/');
Should work fine

And deleting it with:
CookieService.deleteAll()
Also works inside ngOnInit()

I'm pretty sure its the execution order and provide  path as '/' .

That will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete an `httpOnly` cookie in the front-end as it is meant to be unavailable through JS, as said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie)

To delete `httpOnly` cookies, you must make an HTTP call to your backend and delete the cookie in your database. You can set the cookie with a new expiration date to make it expire from the client side.