# Unable to signout when using AWS application load balancer with Azure AD OAuth (OIDC)

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, openid-connect, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a project where I am hosting an ASP.NET MVC site on an AWS EC2 instance behind an AWS application load balancer (ALB).

I have an ALB listener "Authenticate" rule that takes any traffic that does not have a valid cookie and forwards it to the Azure AD OAuth prvoider (aka OIDC Autentication).  The authentication works well, and goes as follows:

1. HTTPS traffic hits my ALB and since there was not a previous OIDC authentication it forwards the user to Microsoft's Azure AD authentication page for my Azure AD tenant.
2. On successful authentication, Azure AD forward the response to my ALBs response URL.  This is where the Azure AD OAuth flow terminates.
3. The AWS ALB generates it's own OAuth token, which includes my original Azure AD username and claims, signs the JWT with it's own key, and forwards the request to my EC2 instance via a target group, with additional HTTP headers (X-Amzn-*) which include the AWS token info

However, I cannot figure out how to sign the authenticated user out.  I have tried

1. Using Azure ADs own "outh2/v2.0/logout" URL with information about my tenant and client ID (application ID) and then specifying a logout page I have hosted behind my AWS ALB,  This only logs out the Azure AD user, but when I return to my site home page the AWS ALB has persisted info via it's own cookie and forwards the traffic without redirecting to Azuure AD with the old AWS JWT (event if the "Exp" timestamp in the JWT has passed).  These subsequent requests contain a cookie named "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0" whose value is the entire JWT encoded in Base64, but with a cookie expiration of 1 week in the future.
2. I have tried clearing the "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0" cookie both on the server side of my application and also in the client code (by setting expiration to some time in the past) prior to hitting my website home page again, but the "AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0" is somehow magically restored containing the old, expired JWT

Is there a prescribed way to logout of an AWS ALB-authenticated session that used Azure AD (with a custom tenant, not the public 'common' tenant) as the OIDC provider?

Answer (score 1):

I configured a `Session timeout` to be as short as 1 second to prevent users from reusing the old cookie.

The `AWSELBAuthSessionCookie-0` is a session cookie containing the `secure` and [httponly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) attributes issued by the load balancer. As [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085756/how-to-delete-session-cookie) points out, the cookie must be changed only on the issuing server.